# How to exclude warnings in Fortify

Tags: java, continuous-integration, devops, fortify

good day, I have the following question I need fortify not to detect a vulnerability in this case an example that I have in java

```
// suppresses validation in sonar 
@SuppresWarnings({"squid:S6654"})
public static String decryptCbc(String key){
..
..
}
```

effectively in sonar I don't get the warning but when I pass the analysis in fortify it shows me the vulnerability is there any way to suppress the validation in fortify as it does in sonar from the code or I have to do something from the pipeline that deploys the application or from fortify itself.

I hope you can give me some idea of how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the vulnerability to the Fortify suppression list.

It will be done within Fortify itself by editing the scan project settings.

Any vulnerability with an ID on the suppression list will be ignored during scanning.

Comment: it was a test I did, but what happens is that with each execution that makes the pipeline creates a version in fortify, if the pipeline goes in the execution 10 creates a version 10 within fortify and so on, then when I remove the vulnerability within the project in version 10 when I resend the analysis and see the version 11 still shows me the vulnerability.